# React hook for logging in anonymously if no other login method

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to have my users log in automatically anonymously. That's not too difficult to do. However I don't want anonymous logins to override their account logins. That's where I am running into trouble. I can't seem to find the way to do this.

Here is my hook:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { singletonHook } from 'react-singleton-hook';
import { useAuth, useUser } from 'reactfire';

function SignInAnonymously() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const user = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    user.firstValuePromise.then(() => {
      if (!user.data) {
        auth.signInAnonymously().then(() => {
          console.log('Signed in anonymously');
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
      }
    });
  }, [user.firstValuePromise, user.data]);

  return <></>;
}

export default singletonHook(<></>, SignInAnonymously);
```

The idea is that we get the first value emitted and compare that to the data object. However, it does not work as I would expect. The value emitted even for someone that was signed in returns null. If I comment the hook the user stays logged into their account. I have spent hours on this trying all the properties of the user so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `useUser()` method of `reactfire`, they use `firebase.auth().currentUser` as the initial value of the observable as seen on [this line](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/blob/81888023e84ec015ed9a91eb744aabec3d2fbecc/src/auth.tsx#L28).

As covered in the [Firebase Authentication docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

> Note: `currentUser` might also be `null` because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

By `reactfire` setting the initial value to `currentUser`, you will often incorrectly get the first value as `null` (which means `firstValuePromise` will also resolve as `null`) because Firebase Auth hasn't finished initializing yet.

To suppress this behaviour, we need specify a value for `initialData` to pass in to `useUser`. I'd love to be able to use `undefined`, but thanks to [this truthy check](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/blob/81888023e84ec015ed9a91eb744aabec3d2fbecc/src/auth.tsx#L31-L33), we can't do that. So we need some truthy value that we can ignore such as `"loading"`.

Applying this to your component gives:

```
/**
 * A truthy value to use as the initial value for `user` when 
 * `reactfire` incorrectly tries to set it to a `null` value
 * from a still-initializing `auth.currentUser` value.
 *
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683276
 */
const USER_LOADING_PLACEHOLDER = "loading";

function SignInAnonymously() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const user = useUser({ initialData: USER_LOADING_PLACEHOLDER });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.data !== null)
      return; // is still loading and/or already signed in
    
    auth.signInAnonymously()
      .then(() => console.log('Signed in anonymously'))
      .catch((e) => console.error('Anonymous sign in failed: ', e));
  }, [user.data]);

  return <></>;
}
```